# Selecting a row in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone

how to make a row in uitableview back to white after selecting.

My problem is when I select a row in uitableview it shows me blue color and it remains on. It doesn't go off, I mean back to white color.

How to do that. any help please..

Answer (score 1):

Conform your class to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and define a delegate method like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```